# Sencha - Add custom attributes to element

Tags: attributes, extjs

I want my div to look like this

```
<div id="example" customAtt="try"></div>
```

How can I add custom attribute to panel,button etc. in sencha?

thank you

Comment: in which version of sencha library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use autoEl in classic framework:

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'component',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    html: 'Hi !!!',
    id: "example",
    autoEl: {
        customAtt: "try"
    }
});
```

Crate ...

```
<div class="x-component x-component-default x-border-box" customatt="try" id="example">Hi !!!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Ext.Component, you can do the following

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function (component) {
        component.getEl().dom.setAttribute("myCustomAttribute", "SOME_VALUE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.Component`'s configuration parameter [ariaAttributes](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Component.html#cfg-ariaAttributes) allows adding attributes to *one* of HTML nodes that constitute that component.

```json
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Button',
    ariaAttributes: {
        'aria-test-id': 'foobar',
        'data-test-id': 'foobar' // looks like any attribute can be inserted this way
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

You can easily add custom attributes, the same way you define config attributes.

```
    mycont = {
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'cont123',
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        customAttribute1: customAttribute1Value
        customAttribute2: customAttribute2Value
        ...
    }
```

Comment: it does not add any custom attribute to the dom element as the OP is pointing.